# .Net app thread/timer performance

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm developing an app that starts a System.Threading.Timer which does some fairly rapid reading/writing to the serial port (every 100ms). The timer's callback method looks something like this:-

```
if (_timerTaskRunning)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("still running");
    return;
}

_timerTaskRunning = true;

... do the serial write/read here ...

_timerTaskRunning = false;
```

The `_timerTaskRunning` flag is a safeguard to ensure that the delegate doesn't run if the previous timer "cycle" hasn't finished, i.e. it's taking longer than 100ms.

When I first start the app I see around a dozen debug messages from the `if` statement. It'll then settle down but I see another group of messages 7 or 8 seconds later. It settles down again, and every once in a while I'll see a group of messages appear in varying numbers.

I'm assuming the first group of messages are caused by the timer delegate running slowly due to the app still starting up, objects/UI initialising, etc, etc, while subsequent messages are perhaps caused by garbage collection kicking in every so often and slowing things down? It's not the serial port because I see the same behaviour with a "mock" serial port.

I've tried delaying the timer's first run by a couple of seconds but it makes no difference - I still get a batch of debug messages for the first second or so after the timer starts. It's not the end of the world skipping some of the timer tasks but it would be interesting to know what might be causing them. Is there anything I can do to investigate the cause further, e.g. would perfmon shed any light on things? I haven't used it before so which counters would you suggest?

Comment: What do you do here `... do the serial write/read here ...`?

Comment: Your read/write code could still execute on 2 separate threads simultaneously.

Comment: @thecoon yes that's where I write to the serial port then read a value back. As mentioned in my question it's not the serial comms causing the dips as I get the same behaviour using a simple "mock" class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have a reentrancy problem. Basically your _timerTaskRunning isn't working as a safeguard likely due to race conditions.

1. Use [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) instead of System.Threading.Timer
2. Set Timer.AutoReset to false. This will fix your entrancing problem because it won't call you call back until you explicitly want it to.
3. Call Start() on your timer when you need it to go again (you may need to adjust the interval to account for execution time)

If you have multiple threads that can call start you will need to synchronize the calls to it.

Comment: The System.Timers.Timer certainly results in cleaner code. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your `_timerTaskRunning` gets updated by several threads. You need to use locking to make it thread-safe.

However, I would not use a timer at all. I have implemented a non-renetrant timer [here](https://gist.github.com/2996519). It uses `AutoResetEvent` WaitOne with timeout which ensures non-reentry.